# How to open an application from email with credentials auto filled

Tags: cross-platform, devops

I am sending an email to my users with credentials. Now I want to create a link, which when clicked opens the applications (which is similar to WinRar) and if possible auto-fill the cred or auto-login.

I am basically looking for ideas on how to achieve this.

All ideas are welcome. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please include the platform you’re programming for. Windows, macOS, Linux, cross platform..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you’re programming on Windows, you need to register a protocol handler: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-3x-wds-ph-install-registration

Your application would register itself as a handler for a protocol, like `myapp://` and then you could include links in emails that would launch your application.

Please consider the security issues when doing this with credentials as arguments. They’ll be visible to the end user and there’s nothing stopping another application from registering as the handler for these URLs and intercepting the credentials.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was wondering if I can create a plugin (ex: for chrome), and the URL triggers the chrome plugin which in turn open the app. Is this possible?